# Rationals to Fractions of integers

Tags: fractions, rational-numbers

How to represent $21.345676767676767...$ as a fraction ?

**MY ATTEMPT :**

$$y=21.34567676767676767...$$

$$1000y=21345.67676767676767...$$

$$1000y=21345+0.67676767676767...$$

$$1000y=21345+\frac{67}{99}$$

$$y=\frac{21345}{1000}+\frac{67}{99000}$$

Am I correct ?

Comment: No, you have $y=1+67/99000=1.00067676767676767676767676767676767\cdots $.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to fix your denominator:
$$
y = \frac{21\,345}{\color{red}{1000}} + \frac{67}{99\,000}
$$
and maybe you'd want to put them together into a *single* fraction, as
$$
= \frac{21\,345\cdot 99}{99\,000} + \frac{67}{99\,000} = \frac{21\,345\cdot 99 + 67}{99\,000}
$$